# How to make a sliding motion using CSS in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ng-animate

Consider the following [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/m1C2ygdR2LOqfkXrM1V6?p=preview)

I am trying to make the list of number slide left upon enter and slide left upon leave.

[image]

Here is my css

```
.stuff {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

button {
  display: block;
}

.stuff.ng-enter,
.stuff.ng-leave {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;

}

.stuff.ng-enter {
    left: 100%;
}
.stuff.ng-enter-active {

    left: 0;
}

.stuff.ng-leave {
    left: 0;
}
.stuff.ng-leave-active {
    left: -100%;
}
```

I verified that if I change positioning transition to opacity it works, but for some reason giving the animation `left` or `right` doesn't work.

Can someone help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just had a look at your code, i'd recommend you add `position` to your styling. you can find the changes [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/GRZH7GvmyDjQ9HC16ta6?p=preview)

i just made a small change to the class.

```
.stuff.ng-enter,.stuff.ng-leave {

 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 position:relative;

}
```

Hope this answers the question .